# net share and CD/DVD drives

Tags: windows, network-shares

I have 2 machines both have Win2K8 R2 Enterprise and if I run the command `net share` on one computer it shows me CD/DVD drive on other it doesnt show CD/DVD.

On both I am running with a user which is a local administrator.

CD/DVD is Not Shared on both machines

Why does it behave differently?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the output you're getting?

Comment: E is my CDROM drive and it shows up when i execute net share, but it doesnt on other machine which also have E as a CDROM

E$           E:\                             Default share
F$           F:\                             Default share